# Consuming SOAP service with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, soap, wsdl

I am trying to do this, for a App with Jquery and Jquery Mobile:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  "http://localhost:8080/CalculatorWS/CalculatorWS?WSDL",
    type : "POST",
    cache : false,
    data : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
           '<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
           '<S:Header/>'+
           '<S:Body>'+
           '<ns2:lista xmlns:ns2="http://calculator.me.org/"/>'+
           '</S:Body>'+
           '</S:Envelope>',
    contentType : "text/xml",
    success : function(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }
}); 

$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, request, settings ) {
    alert (settings.url);
    alert (request.status);
});
```

The first alert with the URL of the Web Service, and in the second alert I got it: `0!`.

What is the problem?

After that if I can get information of SOAP service in Localhost, I hope, I can do it  across the Internet for a App?

Comment: probably needs CORS headers

Comment: I going to do that, thank you.